# Restrict textbox to contain a particular data format - VB

Tags: vb.net, textbox, string-formatting

I have a `textbox` and I want it to accept inputs only in the format of `"xxx_yyy"`  where, `'xxx'` can contain only alphabets (a-z and A-Z) and special characters and `'yyy'` can contain only numbers (0-9).  How to do this?

Comment: Use MaskedTextBox UI element Or use `KeyPress` event for usual TextBox

Comment: Hope someone give an example. Until then here is a link to MSDN documentation, see examples section: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Comment: If you'd wait for a time, I could give that example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here's that example

Drop **MaskedTextBox** element on the form and double click on the form for creating *Form1_Load()* event and see the code

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' Create a mask we want to use. In your case it will be "LLL_000"
    ' Here LLL is 3 ASCI letters. Equivalent to [a-zA-Z] in regular expressions.
    ' _ delimiter
    ' And 000 is 3 digits in range 0-9
    Dim mask As String = "LLL_000"

    ' Assign the mask to MaskedTextBox object
    MaskedTextBox1.Mask = mask
End Sub
```

You may set mask value through Property Editor. Also you need a description label with MaskedTextbox or users gets confused.

More info about formatting masks at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=en-us&k=k(System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox.Mask);k(System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox);k(VS.Properties);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5)&rd=true